# Error in building project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, compiler-construction, visual-c++, linker

While building a c++ project for windows mobile 6.0 , i am getting an error `fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'THUMB'`

i don't no the reason why this error is coming.. i do Google a bit.. since i hv not much idea about instruction set, its tough for me to find..
it will be helpful if i get some info about how to resolve the same...

Thanks
GrabIt

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you are targeting Windows Mobile (ARMv4i) but are pulling in a lib or DLL for an x86 target and trying to link against it.  That won't work.  Use the ARM version.